# Swift: Any way to avoid superclass redundantly initializing fields initialized by subclass?

Tags: swift, initialization, overriding, subclass, required

I have a superclass in swift that declares thinly-wrapped dictionaries.

```
class SomeClass {

    var styleOptions : EntityDictionary<RenderKey,             Any>
    var options      : EntityDictionary<RenderCriteria.Option, Any>
    
    init(_ someClass : SomeClass? = nil) {

       if someClass == nil {
           styleOptions = EntityDictionary([:])
           options = EntityDictionary([:])
       } else {
           styleOptions = someClass.styleOptions
           options = someClass.options
       }
    }
 }
```

By design, subclasses of `SomeClass` will always provide *all* initial values.

So, when subclassing, it's a performance waste for superclass to redundantly initialize everything with empty wrapped-dictionaries.

... yet I don't see a way around the redundant initialization.

*BTW: How expensive is it to initialize with empty dictionaries anyway?*

I messed with override & required, but hit snags, as I can't return from `super.init()` without everything being initialized, yet subclass seems to need `self` to initialize the superclass-defined fields in subclass's init.

Seems to be a Catch-22.

.
.
.

BTW: If they were real Swift dictionaries, I could do something like this in super:

```
 var styleOptions : [ RenderKey, Any ]! = nil
```

Then it wouldn't be necessary to call super.init() from subclass.

However, Swift barfs at `! = nil` appended to the angled bracket form `< >` ...

I'm not sure the proper way to handle this or an acceptable way even.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, maybe I misunderstand your use case, but IMO the main constructor your parent should have is this:

```
init(styleOptions: EntityDictionary<RenderKey, Any>, options: EntityDictionary<RenderCriteria.Option, Any>) {

        self.styleOptions = styleOptions
        self.options = options
    }
```

And for default and "copy init", you can then have convenience inits:

```
    convenience init() {
        self.init(styleOptions: EntityDictionary([:]), options: EntityDictionary<RenderCriteria.Option, Any>([:]))
    }
    
    convenience init(from another: SomeClass? = nil) {
        guard let another = another else {
            self.init()
        }
        
        self.init(styleOptions: another.styleOptions, options: another.options)
    }
```

No extra allocations, and much cleaner interface...

Comment: The problem is my classes have a LOT of the wrapped-dictionaries so that would be a lot of named or ordered optional arguments.  But I will try to re-examine the problem along these lines.

Comment: I guess my point is: you don't create class from another class as main option. You create a class with properties. Additional option could be to create it from another class. If your init has too many parameters, I'd say you need to solve that issue separately (because this or other way, you will have to initialize all properties you have in the class). So maybe Builder, or Composite structure are the ways to improve it...

Comment: Thanks.  Reducing the number of properties is not feasible. It's data-modelish and there are necessarily a lot of them, spread over a number of dictionaries wrapped in a class that has special access/manipulation functions. I don't think the cost of the wasted initialization is enough to worry about in the context it's being used, but wouldn't mind knowing if initializing with an empty dictionary is considered expensive. And finally, I don't need to construct anything if I declare `dict : [ Any, Any ]! = nil` but how do I do that with angled-bracket `< >` format?

Comment: I never ever have any forced unwraps in production code, because mistakes happen: you today remember that it's "a must", but tomorrow someone else will happily skip this property, and... I prefer to solve mistakes like this at compile time, not runtime

Comment: I still think making constructor even with a lot of properties and optionals (where you can actually put the defaults too!) e.g. `init(x: X? = [:], ...)` is a better choice than copy each property inside a constructor

Comment: @sfgblackwakrts Solid advice. Thanks!